# Windows phone 8 store testing kit error

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am using SQLite.WP8 in Windows phone 8 project.
Now when I tried to test with store test kit it says:

> "the application package(XAP) is not up to date,recompile and try
>   again. change the solution configuration to release and platform to
>   any ARM and rebuild the app"

But as I am using sqlite i cannot change to ARM.

Can anyone tell possible solution?

Comment: Are you using `sqlite-wp80-winrt-3080100.vsix` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your IDE? Are you using:

1. Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows phone
2. Visual Studio 2012 Pro or better + Windows Phone SDK
3. Visual Studio 2013 Pro or better + Windows Phone SDK

   I'm assuming that your OS in Windows 8 or 8.1 x64 and you got a intel i5 or i7 CPU (or other cpu with SLAT (Second Layer Address Layer) support).

   You can download the http://www.sqlite.org/download.html#wp8 or instal the extension and see the code in https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8

   There is a nice article and code in http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671